# How to call a method in same class from inside oncreate method android?

Tags: java, android, oncreate

Hi i am new to android & java,  I was trying to make a three buttons menu each time a button is clicked other two changes its color or clicked one is highlighted to show it's selected But i am unable to call a method from inside onCreate to perform a particular task when clicked. Help Thanks `

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int PriceList;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Coffee);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Mocha);
        Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Lattee);
        TextView Counter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Counters);

           mClick(button1,button2,button3)
           mClick(button2,button1,button3)
           mClick(button3,button2,button1)

           Counter.setText(Item()); //Counter is a TextVew, This code doesn't work   

              }

           **/*------------METHODS----------------*/**

     public int TotalValue(int param5){

                if(param5 == 2131427416){   //just Trying to compare with id value 

                 Item();

               Log.d("Item Value " , "onCreate: The value is " + Item()); // works upto here i.e Item()=1

                 } else{
                  // some other code here
                 }
           }

     public int Item(){

          PriceList = 1;

          return PriceList;
         }              

      public void mClick(final Button param1,final Button param2,final Button param3){
            param1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                param2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192,110,99));
                param3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192,110,99));

                int IdNum = param1.getId()

                TotalValue(IdNum);

              }
    });
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Your code would not compile. 2. Where are you defining button1, button2 and button3. Even if the code would compile, you would get a NullPointerException because your buttons are not defined in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define methods **within** methods:

```
public class Example {
  void foo() {
    void bar() { }
  }
```

does not work! Go for:

```
public class Example {
  void foo() {
  }
  void bar() { }
```

instead.

Beyond that, the other basic thing to understand is that in order to have multiple methods work on the same variables, those need to be *fields* of your class, like:

```
public class Example {
  private Button button1

  void onCreate() {
   ...
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   ...
  }

  void foo() {         
   do something with button1
  }
```

Comment: I Still don't get it plz explain ?

Comment: @Misterrai I updated my answer, and also read the other answer really carefully.

Comment: Thanks i got it actually i think i was defining onclick method inside mclick method that was causing the problem .

Answer (score 0):

## old answer

Your problem is about `button's initializations`:

You are calling `MyMethod(mybutton1, mybutton2, mybutton3);`

**but you are never initializating your `buttons` so they will always be `null`.**

Same goes for the `TextView`.

In Android you have to call the init like below:

```
public void onCreate(...){

  Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Coffee);
  Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Mocha);
  Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Lattee);
  TextView Counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Counters);

  mClick(button1,button2,button3);
  mClick(button2,button1,button3);
  mClick(button3,button2,button1);

  Counter.setText(Item()); //Counter is a TextVew, This code doesn't work   

}
```

[Check for those videos on youtube](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUp4-cs4DSAhXEtRoKHWlxDtQQtwIIIzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DQAbQgLGKd3Y&usg=AFQjCNFg1xjVLl0Eg09-BwV5s1pe4pnAKQ&sig2=V1TqxmidEoliwtLMlpAiKg&bvm=bv.146094739,d.d2s), they are the best for android beginners **imho**.

Good luck! for any help I'm here

## Improvements:

This is how your code should looks like. Remember to format the code for a better comprehension:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private int priceList;
    
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    TextView counter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Counter);

    mClick(button1,button2,button3)
    mClick(button2,button1,button3)
    mClick(button3,button2,button1)

    counter.setText(Item()); //Dont' use capital letters for variable's name
  }

           **/*------------METHODS----------------*/**

  public int TotalValue(int param5){

    if(param5 == 2131427416){   //just Trying to compare with id value 
      Item();
      Log.d("Item Value " , "onCreate: The value is " + Item()); // works upto here i.e Item()=1

    } else{
      // some other code here
    }
  }

  public int Item(){
    priceList = 1;
    return priceList;
  }              

  public void mClick(final Button param1,final Button param2,final Button param3){
    param1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view){
        param2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192,110,99));
        param3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192,110,99));
        int idNum = param1.getId()
        TotalValue(idNum);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

There were some points:

- One extra closing brace at the end
- (convention) don't call a variable with capital lecter
- I didn't change your methods's names and variables's names, but consider using something more explicative (still a convention, but it's for a better comprehension)
- You didn't had the `;` after the method's call

## Improvements's update:

You were missing the `;` after the `mClick(..)` calls.

Comment: Sorry i didnt add full code earlier , edited it again  I already had all buttons & TextView objects defined still it doen't work please have a look again

Comment: @Misterrai check the edited code and try running it. If it gives you any error please post it

Answer (score 0):

From My understanding of what you want you could use this

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int PriceList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Coffee);
        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mocha);
        final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Lattee);
        TextView Counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Counters);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 110, 99));
                button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 110, 99));
                int IdNum = button1.getId();
                TotalValue(IdNum);

            }
        });
        Counter.setText(Item()); //Counter is a TextVew, This code doesn't work
    }

    public int TotalValue(int param5) {
        if (param5 == 2131427416) {   //just Trying to compare with id value
            Item();
            Log.d("Item Value ", "onCreate: The value is " + Item()); // works upto here i.e Item()=1
        } else {
            // some other code here
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int Item() {
        PriceList = 1;
        return PriceList;
    }
}
```

If not please comment exact need so i could help

Comment: Thanks for your help but i think this might not work as this is valid if i click button1 but won't work for other buttons (button2 & button3 ) . The main idea behind using parameters was to change value of button1 evrytime. Thanks